# proxyhost mysql-server

Tags: apt, server, proxy

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libevent-core-2.1-6 libhtml-template-perl mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
Suggested packages:
  libipc-sharedcache-perl mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libevent-core-2.1-6 libhtml-template-perl mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 20.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 160 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mysql-common all 5.8+1.0.4
  Could not resolve 'proxyhost'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libaio1 amd64 0.3.110-5
  Could not resolve 'proxyhost'
....
```

Comment: You have configured your system to use a proxy named `proxyhost`. This host does not resolve. Remove proxy configuration, or verify that it is correct and try again.

Comment: Welcome to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1107057/edit) your question including the output of `cat /etc/hosts |grep proxyhost`